# My sections overflow on other section with mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, overflow

I added 2 pictures on my main page and everything looks good on the browser but when I check the website with my phone, it's like the picture overflow in the next section instead of staying in the first section.

I've added the following code in my html for the pictures:

> [ms_divider style="blank" align="left"  width="100%" margin_top="30px" margin_bottom="0" border_size="" border_color="" icon="" class="" id=""]
>   [ms_row no_padding="yes"]
>   [ms_column style="1/2"]
>   [ms_image_frame src="http://www.landrycarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/IMG_4775.jpg" link="http://www.landrycarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/IMG_4775.jpg" link_target="_self" class="" id=""][/ms_column]
>
> [ms_column style="1/2"] [ms_image_frame
>   src="http://www.landrycarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/landrycarts-budpatrol-limo.jpg"
>   link="http://www.landrycarts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/landrycarts-budpatrol-limo.jpg"
>   link_target="_self" class="" id=""][/ms_column] [/ms_row]

Any way I could limit those pictures in my first section for mobile view?

[My website](http://www.landrycarts.com)

Comment: Which images you are talking in website

Comment: Everything looks fine in mobile view

Comment: the last cart "bud patrol" overflows in my "about" section on my iphone

Comment: Before about section there contact section having no images, i checked my iphone also give me image name like image.jpg something.. If you not fixed yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `max-height` and `overflow: hidden;` on your `img` parent `col-md-6`?

Heres a [demo](http://codepen.io/isaacminogue/pen/jqaVyw) illustrating this.

Comment: I changed the design of the front page at the end, but I tried what you suggested and it solved my overflow problem. Thank you!